# How apply MMS Navigation Security Trim in SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2016

In SharePoint 2016 How to apply security Trim.

We want navigation Items globally But In Site pages Some of navigation Items(Some of Navigation Links) will be visible some of group user only.

For this We are using MMS Navigation. Is there any way to apply Security Trim

Thanks